# Create 2 tabular next to each other with an arrow in between

Tags: tables, formatting, texmaker

first time poster here.

I am currently stuck on one thing.

I want to create this

[image]

I started the LaTeX code (but the thing I don't know how to do is keep everything on the same line and have an arrow in the middle).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage [margin=1in] {geometry}

\parindent 0px %no indention

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  &   4 & 3 \\
- &    1 & 5 \\
\hline
  &    &  \\
\end{tabular} \\

\vspace{0.5 cm}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  &   3 & 13 \\
- &    1 & 5 \\
\hline
  &   2 & 8 \\
\end{tabular} \\

\end{document}
```

So it looks like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options. The length of the arrow can be controlled by adjusting the argument of `\hspace*`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article} 
%\usepackage{bookman} % not needed here
\usepackage{amsmath} 
%\usepackage{fullpage} % not needed here
%\usepackage{graphicx} % not needed here
%\usepackage{amsmath} % loaded twice
\usepackage[margin=1in] {geometry}
\parindent 0px %no indention
\begin{document}
\[\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
    & 4 & 3 \\
    & 1 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    & & \\ 
\end{tabular}}}
\xrightarrow{\hspace*{3em}}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
    & 3 & 13 \\
    & 1 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    & 2 & 8 \\ 
\end{tabular}}}\]
or
\[\begin{tabular}[m]{ccc} 
    & 4 & 3 \\
    & 1 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    & & \\ 
\end{tabular}
\xrightarrow{\hspace*{3em}}
\begin{tabular}[m]{ccc} 
    & 3 & 13 \\
    & 1 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    & 2 & 8 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\]
or 
$\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
    & 4 & 3 \\
    & 1 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    & & \\ 
\end{tabular}}}
\xrightarrow{\hspace*{3em}}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
    & 3 & 13 \\
    & 1 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    & 2 & 8 \\ 
\end{tabular}}}$
or
$\begin{tabular}[m]{ccc} 
    & 4 & 3 \\
    & 1 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    & & \\ 
\end{tabular}
\xrightarrow{\hspace*{3em}}
\begin{tabular}[m]{ccc} 
    & 3 & 13 \\
    & 1 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    & 2 & 8 \\ 
\end{tabular}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]